# Alining 2 background images that change on window resize (background-size: cover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image on body and my sidebar, same one. Reason to have it on sidebar is to create blur effect latter, therefore I need part of the image in sidebar to perfectly match one of the body.

Ignoring fact that image is darker in sidebar, they should perfectly align no matter how window is resized, I tried various attempts, however am not able to figure this one out.

Related code:

```
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #2B3540;
      background-image: url(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ilja.io/images/background.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #sidebar {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(43, 53, 64, 0.7);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar::before {
      background-image: url(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ilja.io/images/background.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      content: '';
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -5;
      display: block;
      /*-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
      -moz-filter: blur(10px);
      -o-filter: blur(10px);
      -ms-filter: blur(10px);
      filter: blur(10px);*/
    }
```

where `#sidebar` is simply `<aside>` element within body.

My initial approach was to blur sidebar, however that results in a completely different effect, hence I need to use a `::before` element with same background image and blur it instead.

Comment: We will need more code then that to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith added

Comment: Have you confirmed that you don't get the desired blur effect if you simply don't add the background image to the sidebar?

Comment: @csum If you uncomment last bit of css you can see it, it sort of works, but if you check on ui's like iOS, that blur effect looks much cleaner if everything is aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is acceptable, but it does line them up

```
body {
  ...
  background-position: left center;
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend playing with viewport units to position left sidebar background correctly.

Comment: I actually tried this, it works up to a certain screen resolution, if it gets bigger than original image size, body background image starts being stretched and they are out of alignment again.

Comment: But I ended up making image very wide, so this approach works for most cases.

Comment: @Ilja You can also try adding `background-size: auto 100vmax;` to both the `body` and the sidebar. IE doesn't support `vmax` so you can use a media rule on `orientation` with `vw` and `vh` accordingly.